# How to return and use multiple values in functions in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am would like to write a user defined function (UDF), `A` that returns multiple values (let's say 3).  I would then like to use these values in another UDF, `B`.

I have been following 
https://www.geeksengine.com/article/vba-function-multiple-values2.html
on what VBA data structures would support this.  I was originally using a `collection` to store the multiple values from UDF `A`,  but in my use case, index 0, 1 and 2 have some value, so would like to use an `array` instead of a `collection` so that I can index with base 0 (I am not sure if this is possible with `collections` - it seems the first element is `.Item(1)`).

The problem is, I cannot seem to retrieve the values of the array returned by UDF A inside UDF B.

A minimum (not) working example:

```
Function A() As Variant

    Dim arr(3) As Variant

    arr(0) = "zero"
    arr(1) = "one"
    arr(2) = "two"

    A = arr

    MsgBox "Function A"
    MsgBox arr(0)

End Function


Function B() As Variant

    Dim arry(3) As Variant
    Set arry = A()

    MsgBox "Function B"
    MsgBox arry(0)


    End Function

Sub debugfunc()
    MsgBox B() 
End Sub
```

I have tried both `Set arry = A()` and `arry = A()`.  Both produce 'Ca't assign to array' errors when running the debugfunc sub.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't assign to array is because of `Dim arry(3)`. You cannot assign to an array `Dim`ed with dimensions. Dim without dimensions.

Comment: Please note that these Functions may be used as UDFs. However, the example code does not do that. A UDF (User Defined Function) is a function that you intend to call in an Excel Formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use `Set` and you need a dynamic array of the same type to receive the function result:

```
Dim arry() As Variant
arry = A()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `arry` as `Variant` and get rid of `Set`.
Here is your code corrected:

```
Function A() As Variant
    Dim arr(3) As Variant
    arr(0) = "zero"
    arr(1) = "one"
    arr(2) = "two"
    A = arr
    MsgBox "Function A"
    MsgBox arr(0)
End Function

Function B() As Variant
    Dim arry As Variant: arry = A()
    MsgBox "Function B"
    MsgBox arry(0)
End Function

Sub debugfunc()
    MsgBox B()
End Sub
```

You may also remove the parens after `A`, like `Dim arry As Variant: arry = A()`.